# Missing my last bird in Botanicula, at restaurant

Tags: botanicula

There is a level in Botanicula where you have to collect 18 birds. When I enter the biggest house, there are just a few things I can do:

1. Get food for another room
2. Click the bird
3. Pick up salt

(1.) I have gotten the food. (2.) Clicking the bird seems hopeless. (3) What should I do with the salt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you pick up the salt with Mr. Feather, there are a several things you can do with it.

**Hint 1:**

> You can shake it over the soup and over the other creatures in the restaurant.

**Hint 2:**

> Try shaking it over the head of the large sleeping creature on the far right side.

**Solution:**

> Using the mouse, move Mr. Feather over the head of the large sleeping creature on the far right.
>  Shake the mouse like a salt shaker.
>  When the large sleeping creature wakes up, he will distract the chef, and you can pick up the bird.